# Lazyvim/Neovim Formatting Issue upon saving: A space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >') (fix available) clang

Tags: c++, neovim

In my LazyVim/NeoVim setup, everytime I save a file, my files are formatted.

Using Mason, I installed clangd LSP and clangd-format. Unfortunately, it always removes the space between consecutive >, which does not allow my Makefile to compile my code. I'm working in C++98 for a school project. As I understand, this is a necessity in code pre C++11, yet the formatter keeps removing this space.

I have been looking for a fix here: https://github.com/clangd/clangd but cannot seem to locate a sort of config file where I could change this option.

Comment: Do you have a compile_flags.txt file you use? If so, try adding `-std=c++98` to that file (replacing an existing language version if any is specified).

Comment: I have something similar called compile_commands.json which I generate with the compiledb -n make. I initially started using this json to indicate the correct includes folder for my project.

It already contains this though:
```
[
 {
  "directory": "/Users/Hendrik/Documents/Coding/42/42_projects/ft_containers",
  "arguments": [
   "c++",
   "-Wall",
   "-Wextra",
   "-Werror",
   "-std=c++98"...
```

Attempting to disable autoformatting for now from an nvim-lspconfig file as defined in the docs at https://www.lazyvim.org/plugins/lsp#nvim-lspconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this pesky issue. Here are steps below!

1. navigate to project root directory
2. launch this cmd: `clang-format -style=file -dump-config > .clang-format` (you might need to install llvm with brew (MacOS): `brew install llvm`)
3. enter .clang-format, replace the line Standard: Latest to Standard: C++03